# How to add 2 list from a function without using global variables?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, arguments

In this problem, I need to create a function that first initialize 2 lists.

```
def inscription():
    listeJudo = [150, 250, 190, 230]
    listePatinage = [110, 200, 125, 130]
```

I then need to call another function that ADDS these 2 lists together and do a SUM of the elements inside those list. I'm not allowed to use global variables. How can this be done using functions arguments?

What is the correct way of passing the lists as arguments to my other function?

```
def addLists():
    sumLists = inscription(listeJudo+listePatinage)
```

?

Comment: Just pass the lists as arguments to the other function. Lists are *just objects*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is how to pass arguments to function and returns result.

I add your function with modification - now it returns lists

```
def inscription():
    list_1 = [150, 250, 190, 230]
    list_2 = [110, 200, 125, 130]
    return list_1, list_2

def add_lists(first_list, second_list):
    #results = sum(first_list+second_list)

    results = []
    for a, b in zip(first_list, second_list):
        results.append(a+b)

    return results

listeJudo, listePatinage = inscription()

sum_lists = add_lists(listeJudo, listePatinage)
```

Comment: Using this method I get error that my lists are not defined, since they are from my first function. I can't use a global variable to use them in other functions.

Comment: Your answer is under review for being a low quality answer. Please provide an explanation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I get from your question,  you want another function to add the lists together and then sum the elements?

```
def inscription():
 listeJudo = [150, 250, 190, 230]
 listePatinage = [110, 200, 125, 130]
 sumOfLists = sumLists(listeJudo, listePatinage)

def sumLists(first, second):
  sumOfValuesList = [x + y for x, y in zip(first, second)]
  sumOfCombinedList = sum(sumOfValuesList)
  return sumOfCombinedList
```

Comment: Right. The first function works fine, but as soon is I get to the second, I get that my lists are not defined.